# Android Studio fuzzy looking on Windows PC

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, resolution

I'm running Android Studio on my Windows 7 PC and noticed that the application had what appeared to be poor resolution. The text was fuzzy and the things just looked far from crisp and clear. I have a monitor with a high resolution and everything else looks good and clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the cause was the Windows system Theme that I had set. i was running on a custom theme that I had created, and this was the issue. I changed my theme to "Windows 7 Basic", relaunched Android Studio, and everything was looking great. I'm not sure what other themes will work and still give a good-looking resolution, but "Windows 7 Basic" works perfectly for me. I changed the theme by going to Control Panel > Change Theme > Windows 7 Basic.